# String Reverse : reversing only position of the Words in String in c#

Tags: c#

original String is "Hello World"

Output Should be "World Hello"

What is the optimized way to do it in c# ?

Please suggest me any existing link if i am missing

Comment: What is your current approach?

Comment: I am getting Program to complete String Reversal letter by letter, I dont want to do that ... i can post example if you want

Answer (score 4):

```
var s = "Hello world";
var result = String.Join(" ", s.Split(' ').Reverse()));
```

OR (better split below if you ar not sure of your data)

```
var s = "Hello world";
var result = String.Join(" ", Regex.Split(s, @"\s").Reverse());
```

Answer (score 1):

I would split the sentence by the words (the space between them):

```
string[] words = helloString.Split(" ");
helloString = words[1] + " " + words[0];
```

You could optimise this to work with any sentence with any number of words by looping through `words` from the last element to the first.

I've reassigned the new string back to helloString (the original) as I assume this is what you want based on the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code :

```
  string value = "Hello world";
  string firstvalue = value.Split(' ').First();
  string secvalue = value.Split(' ').Last();
  string value = secvalue + firstvalue;
```

Comment: Then Use Foreach Condition For More than 2 Words

Answer (score 0):

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String str = "Hello World";
        String[] strNames = str.Split(' ');
        for(int i=strNames.Length-1;i>=0;i--)
        Console.Write(strNames[i]+" ");
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
char[] Delimiter = new char[] { ' ' }
string[] t = string.split("Hello Wordl", Delimiter)
int lenS = t.Count;
string result = "";
for(int x =t-1; t > -1; t--)
{
  result += t[x] + " ";
}

//Used result now
```

Comment: Are you sure about this `&=`?

Comment: Oh sorry that is +=, got interchanged with VB.Net

Comment: That would add extra space in the end.